# Location-search in Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I just experimented with a location-search on careers 2.0 for `balkans` and lo and behold one result was returned! Very nice feature, although I noticed that the result header was broken showing only `1 job near`.

I very much like this feature and also tried searches for `Scandinavia` which again returned results! Obviously you match the input to some background geo-ontology or something, but I feel this functionality is a bit hidden from the users. A nice auto-suggest or something similar might make it more usable.

Thank you!

Comment: umm... I don't understand what you are trying to say. what is your feature request? what is the bug?

Comment: The bug is that the results header does not display the name of the location used for search, as it would if I entered the name of a city. The feature request is to make it transparent to the users that they can search not only by city/country but other geographical locations as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there were a few locations in our database which didn't have proper names associated with them. Reason was that they were larger than countries, but smaller than continents. Struggling with their identity, they fell through the cracks. This should now be fixed.

You might wanna move the "distance" slider all the way to the right when searching those kind of large regions to get a good number of results.

And in case anyone's curious what other super-country, sub-continental locations our users apparently have been searching for in the past - here's a small selection:

- Scandinavia
- Central America
- Eastern Europe
- Northern Europe
- North Africa
- Oceania
- Eurasia
- Czechoslovakia (which proves: Careers 2.0 must have been popular even before 1993)